# I need to format a write statement in python to format it to a text file. I also am not sure how to keep the updated list when writing the file

Tags: python, text-files

I know it's not completely finished, but I'm very confused as how to format the save inventory function so it prints like the original text file. During the add_item function, it shows that the item has been added to the lists. But when going to write nothing is there or updated.

[Example of how the text file needs to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pOPD.jpg)

```
def save_inventory(inventoryFile, descriptionArray, quantityArray, priceArray, intrecords):
        outfile = open(inventoryFile, "w")
        with open('inventory1.txt', 'r') as f:
            count = -1
            for line in f:
                count+=1
                if count % 3 == 0: #this is the remainder operator
                    outfile.write(descriptionArray)
                    print(descriptionArray)
        with open('inventory1.txt', 'r') as f:
            count = -2
            for line in f:
                count+=1
                if count % 3 == 0: #this is the remainder operator
                    outfile.write(str(quantityArray))
                    print(quantityArray)
        with open('inventory1.txt', 'r') as f:
            count = -3
            for line in f:
                count+=1
               if count % 3 == 0: #this is the remainder operator
                    outfile.write(str(priceArray))
                    print(priceArray)
        outfile.close()
```

Comment: Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: don't put all in title - it should be short.

Comment: if you need text file then don't use picle. Use standard `open()`, `write()`, `close()`. And you may need `for` loop to save every element separatelly. BTW: don't forget to add `\n` after every line.

Comment: better check items in `save_inventory`, not in `add_item` - maybe you run `save_inventory` with empty arrays.

Comment: @furas, I think that might be the problem. How would I check that? I'm still pretty new at this. I also took out the pickle.

Comment: use `print()` to display items - and you will see on screen what you have in variables. You can also use full path in `inventoryFile` because it can save in different folder. And run in console/terminal/cmd.exe to see any error message.

Comment: I don't know why do you read file `inventory1.txt` if you don't use its lines - you only count  lines. But if `inventory1.txt` is empty then you write nothing in `inventoryFile`.

Comment: if `descriptionArray` is list/array then `outfile.write(str(quantityArray))` will write it with extra `[ ]`. Better use `for` loop to write every element separatelly. `for item in descriptionArray: outfile.write(item + '\n')`

Comment: I don't know why do you open `'inventory1.txt'` and read it. If this file is empty then  `for line in f:` will never run and it will never execute `outfile.write(str(priceArray))` nor `outfile.write(descriptionArray)` nor `outfile.write(descriptionArray)`. So main question is why do you read `'inventory1.txt'` and what you have inside.

Comment: I have no idea how to get it to write the way I need it. In other functions, things that have been added show but it prints nothing to the text file. I'm not sure why the list changes when they get to the last function.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. If you have a suggestion I'm willing to try anything at this point. I tried the for item in descriptionArray: outfile.write(item + '\n') and it came back with an error. unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only writing to the file when you have read a line. If your text file is empty you will never write to the file.

What I would do is [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) the lists together and loop through them. Then write three lines to the file for each pass through the loop. You can print a carriage return with '\n'

```
with open(inventoryFile, 'w') as f:
    for d, q, p in zip(descriptionArray, quantityArray, priceArray):
        f.write('%s\n%s\n%s\n' % (d, q, p))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You just helped me out so much!